# How to render dynamic content from mysql using php to webpage in a three column divs format in a div row

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic, content-management-system

I have a div, which is a div containing three(3) other divs which are now display using display inline-flex.

row1

```
<div style="display:inline-flex;">
    <div> dynamic content <div>
    <div> dynamic content <div>
    <div> dynamic content <div> 
</div>
```

i want each row should be generated dynamically, using PHP and content dynamic from MySQL.

here is what i tried but not working, need help with this.

The code was suppose to query mysql to get an array and pass to php to create the divs and mother div. untill it's out on arrays from mysql.

```
$idurl = $_GET['u'];

 $gets = [];
 $stmts = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM quickiimessage WHERE token =? ");


 $stmts->bind_param("s", $idurl);
 $stmts->execute();
 $result = $stmts->get_result();
 if (!$result->num_rows > 0 ) {

 header("location:quickii.php");
 }
 /*
 if ($result->num_rows === 1 ) exit(header("location:quickii.php"));*/
 while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){

 $gets[] = $row;
}$get[] = var_export($gets);
 /*
  $post_author[] = $row['message'];
  $timestamp[] = $row['dates'];*/
$card = 0;
for ($loaddiv=0; $loaddiv<=1 ; $loaddiv++) {
echo "<div class=\"three_columns\">";
    while ( $card <= 3 ) {
        echo "<div class=\"card\">


            <div class=\"socialdiv\">
                <a style=\"color:red;\" href=\"#\" class=\"fa fa-facebook\"></a style=\"color:mediumblue;\">
<a style=\"color:red;\" href=\"#\" class=\"fa fa-twitter\"></a>
            </div>
            <a href=\"\">
            <!--<p>Overall rating:<img src=\"icons/Untithjkled.png\"></p>-->
            <div class=\"names\">  <div class=\"icons-internationalnews\"> <a href=\"\">Anonymous user</a> </div> </div>
            <div class=\"texts\">
                <span class=\"cliprendername\">  $gets['message'] </span>
                    <span class=\"clip_chan_name\"></span> <br>
                    <span class=\"renderclips_views\">$gets['dates'] </span> <br><br>
        </a>



            <br><br>
            </div>
    </a> </div>
";
$card = $card++;
 }
    if ($loaddiv = 1) {
        echo "</div>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, because nobody will code a solution for you.For example you can loop your query result with a php foreach...

Comment: can you show your SQL queries and php code so that people can help you

Comment: there is some information that you probably have that we need to answer the question.  your question is tagged `content-management-system` which suggests that you have access to a framework that provides a list of objects that are accessible in PHP.  without knowing more about that any answer you receive is not going to help you enough.

Comment: i just added the code, above